# In Excel VBA, position a workbook precisely over a form control

Tags: excel, vba, position, window, coordinates

Here's what I want to achieve:

1. From the main workbook, display a userform. (this is easy)
2. While initializing the userform, open a secondary workbook. (this is easy)
3. Once the secondary workbook is open, set its top, left, width and height properties such that the workbook appears precisely positioned over a Frame1 control on the userform.

The result of all of this is that the secondary workbook appears as a virtual spreadsheet control on the form.

I have be iterating with various means of determining the screen coordinates of the form and the Frame1 control without a final result. Various Win32 APIs seem to get to parts of it, e.g., GetSystemMetrics, GetDeviceCaps, FindWindow, WindowFromPoint, etc.

A complicating factor is that I won't know that screen resolution of the operating environment. The task seems akin to translating French into Russian, then into Latin, then into Aztec, and finally into binary. I need a Rosetta Stone. But alas.

Anyone got that Rosetta Stone?

Thanks,

Bob

PS. Note that OWC11 is not a satisfactory option for a number of reasons, including it's limitation in displaying conditional cell formatting, availability of some necessary Excel functions and because it is deprecated.

Comment: you want users to interact with the 2nd workbook or is it just for viewing purpose?

Comment: The users need to interact.

Answer (score 0):

To get the screen resolution of the operating environment, you can use the code:

```
Private Declare Function GetSystemMetrics32 Lib "User32" _
Alias "GetSystemMetrics" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetDC Lib "user32" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" _
(ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hDC As Long) As Long

Private Const LOGPIXELSX = 88 'Might be wrong as online says 96
Private Const LOGPIXELSY = 96
Private Const POINTS_PER_INCH As Long = 72

Public Function PointsPerPixel() As Double
    Dim hDC As Long
    Dim lDotsPerInch As Long
    hDC = GetDC(0)
    lDotsPerInch = GetDeviceCaps(hDC, LOGPIXELSX)
    PointsPerPixel = POINTS_PER_INCH / lDotsPerInch
    ReleaseDC 0, hDC
End Function

Public Function PixelsPerPoint() as Double
    Dim hDC As Long
    Dim lDotsPerInch As Long
    hDC = GetDC(0)
    lDotsPerInch = GetDeviceCaps(hDC, LOGPIXELSX)
    PixelsPerPoint = lDotsPerInch / POINTS_PER_INCH
    ReleaseDC 0, hDC
End Function

Function ScreenRes() as Double()
    Dim resolution(2) as Double
    resolution(0) = GetSystemMetrics32(0) ' width in points
    resolution(1) = GetSystemMetrics32(1) ' height in points
    ScreenRes = Resolution
End Function
```

To get the Resolution use `ScreenRes()`. Then you can find the forms location using `formName.left` and `formName.top`, and I believe it is a point-based location. You could have the code either convert this to Pxl's, or convert your screen size to points. Then to move the excel workbook you can use `Application.left` and `Application.top`, and I'm pretty sure this is in points as well.

If you want to format it nicer for the screen, you can also use the `Application.width` and `Application.height` in conjunction with `formName.width` and `formName.height`. You can check if the bounds of the form are off screen by using `if (formName.left + formName.width) > (PixelsToPoint *(ScreenRes)(0)) and (formName.left > 0)` and a similar form for height.

There is likely errors in my code as I haven't checked it in VBA but hopefully this is a start to what you need. If someone wants to make an edit to my code I would be extremely grateful, and hopefully what I have said helps as your question was slightly vague.

Comment: Thanks Riley. I will try this. It looks like you might be translating some code yourself. By,

    Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();

I think you mean, 

    Dim g As Graphic
    g = this.CreateGraphics()

The translation I can't figure out is, 

    g.Dispose():

The Graphic object doesn't have a "dispose" method, or anything near it really. Should I just, 

    Set g = Nothing

Comment: My bad, I modified the code to what I typically use in my VBA code as I don't create a graphics object every time and instead utilize DLL functions. Source: https://books.google.com/books?id=VnegO0pMYlIC&pg=PA339&lpg=PA339&dq=Dim+hDC+As+Long+Dim+lDotsPerInch+As+Long+hDC+%3D+GetDC(0)&source=bl&ots=DxCHRkRaPu&sig=aFZ95afPrJCTSQHpMy5eXLkd4xU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiOv9WFnNrfAhV_CjQIHQpcCWkQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=Dim%20hDC%20As%20Long%20Dim%20lDotsPerInch%20As%20Long%20hDC%20%3D%20GetDC(0)&f=false